# I have tried to update ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, apt

Update gets failed. Then I shut down my laptop and now when I started it again it isn't started with gui and then I read the same query at sight which tells to do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> to use command line  and to do `sudo apt-get update` after logging in and then to do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

But when I tried to do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it is facing with some interrupt "dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem". I tried many times but same problem is there each time.
What should I do  to fix it?

Comment: Should i run "sudo dpkg --cofigure -a"

Comment: Indeed. Package management is now in an inconsistent state, and this command might repair it. If this succeeds, continuing the install from the command line might work. A cleaner and more foolproof approach, however, would be to do a fresh install, overwriting your old installation. Make sure your backup is up to date (which should be even when trying an upgrade over an existing system).

Comment: After doing this command gui starts working but is not properly active like some icons have question mark(?).     Wallpapers are not going to be set . (Some basics which i checked)

Comment: Should i update it now?

Comment: What version are you now? `lsb_release -a`. It not yet on the new version, indeed you could try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: It is 16.04 lts now working.

Comment: It is showing to do using -f .reson behind specified is unmet dependencies